# How to get all addresses for a long list of companies affordably

Tags: database, business-intelligence, geography

My firm works with thousands of companies. Some of them have one or two physical locations (stores and offices), but many have hundreds or thousands of stores/offices across all 50 U.S. states.

I proposed to my firm that we ought to gather, store, and maintain a list of all the locations. The information is available on Hoovers.com and similar sites. We could write our own software to utilize the Hoovers.com API to get the information, but there is a cost per amount of data, and the initial "pull" of data would be massive. (Weekly maintenance would be much more lightweight.)

What software / databases exist that could provide this information affordably? Are there options?

Comment: Have you looked into using the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)?

Comment: @Huey Thanks for that idea, but it appears that if the data isn't available on a public website (which is our situation), we'd have to pay for the service. I also didn't see a simple way to find all the addresses of, say, Walmart or FedEx.